# R - apply to replace for loop with functions

Tags: r, for-loop, apply, nested-loops

I have seen a dozen sites to learn apply, sapply, lapply, but they don't get much farther than teaching you how to take the sum or mean of a row or column. I have to use a lot of for loops, often nested. Please show me how to replace for with apply in the following.

```
for (i in 1:NTR) {
    X = as.vector(as.matrix(XTR[i,]))
    YZ = FN(W, V, U, X) # return Y and Z
    Y = YZ$Y
    Z = YZ$Z
    for (j in 1:NOUT) {
        F[i+NOUT*(j-1)] = Y[j]-YTR[i,j]
    } # j
} # i
```

and

```
    for (k in 1:NOUT) {
        for (iwt in 1:NWT) {
            m = NHID*(NNLIN+1) 
            if (iwt <= m) { 
                i = (iwt-1) %/% (NNLIN+1) + 1
                j = (iwt-1) %% (NNLIN+1)
                EVZ = V[k,i+1]*Z[i]*(1-Z[i]) 
                if (j>0) EVZ = EVZ*X[j] 
                J[k+(n-1)*NOUT,iwt] = EVZ
            }
        } # iwt     
    } # k
```

Thanks very much for any replies.

Comment: Your examples may make sense to you, but without context they may not make sense to others. What are are the inputs and expected outputs for the code?

Answer (score 17):

The easiest way to transform a loop into an lapply is to take what's inside your for loop and plug it inside a function. Let's start with your inner loop.

```
foo_inner <- function(j) {
    F[i+NOUT*(j-1)] = Y[j]-YTR[i,j]
}
```

There is one problem here though: your function should return a value instead of assigning it. In this case, you want to return `Y[j]-YTR[i,j]`.

```
foo_inner <- function(j) {
    return(Y[j]-YTR[i,j])
}
```

You can then simply apply this function to `1:NOUT`. In this case, it seems (though I can't be sure given the lack of info in your post) that this return value is just a number so that you can create a vector directly instead of a list. In this case, it is better to use `sapply` rather than `lapply` (the 's' stands for simplify (to a vector) while the 'l' means list):

```
sapply(1:NOUT, foo_inner)
```

This new vector must now be assigned in your outer loop. From your code, it appears you want to assign this vector to `F[i+NOUT*(1:NOUT-1)]`. I simply replaced your `j` value by `1:NOUT` which is your iterator. Your code snippet can therefore be modified like thus:

```
for (i in 1:NTR) {
    X = as.vector(as.matrix(XTR[i,]))
    YZ = FN(W, V, U, X) # return Y and Z
    Y = YZ$Y
    Z = YZ$Z
    F[i+NOUT*(1:NOUT-1)] <- sapply(1:NOUT, foo_inner)
} # i
```

Let's tackle the outer loop now. As before, we can plug what's inside in a function:

```
foo_outer <- function(i) {
    X = as.vector(as.matrix(XTR[i,]))
    YZ = FN(W, V, U, X) # return Y and Z
    Y = YZ$Y
    Z = YZ$Z
    F[i+NOUT*(1:NOUT-1)] <- sapply(1:NOUT, foo_inner)
}
```

There is here two problems to overcome: First, your `foo_inner` function takes `i` as parameter. But, `foo_inner` being defined outside `foo_outer`, it will always use the `i` defined in your environment and not the argument of `foo_outer`. There are two solutions to this: either define `foo_inner` inside `foo_outer`:

```
foo_outer <- function(i) {
    X = as.vector(as.matrix(XTR[i,]))
    YZ = FN(W, V, U, X) # return Y and Z
    Y = YZ$Y
    Z = YZ$Z
    foo_inner <- function(j) {
        return(Y[j]-YTR[i,j])
    }
    F[i+NOUT*(1:NOUT-1)] <- sapply(1:NOUT, foo_inner)
}
```

Or, modify your `foo_inner` function so that it takes `i` as parameter and returns a correct function. You will then apply the function `foo_inner(i)` inside the inner `sapply` rather than `foo_inner`:

```
foo_inner <- function(i) {
    function(j) {
        return(Y[j]-YTR[i,j])
    }
}
foo_outer <- function(i) {
    X = as.vector(as.matrix(XTR[i,]))
    YZ = FN(W, V, U, X) # return Y and Z
    Y = YZ$Y
    Z = YZ$Z
    F[i+NOUT*(1:NOUT-1)] <- sapply(1:NOUT, foo_inner(i))
}
```

The next modification to do is to ensure you want to return a value rather than doing an assignment inside your function:

```
foo_inner <- function(i) {
    function(j) {
        return(Y[j]-YTR[i,j])
    }
}
foo_outer <- function(i) {
    X = as.vector(as.matrix(XTR[i,]))
    YZ = FN(W, V, U, X) # return Y and Z
    Y = YZ$Y
    Z = YZ$Z
    return(sapply(1:NOUT, foo_inner(i)))
}
```

You can now apply this function:

```
lapply(1:NTR, foo_outer)
```

In this case, I used an `lapply` as each element returned will be a vector so I'd rather return a list and collapse it afterwards as I'm not sure if that's what `sapply` does in this case (and am too lazy to find out at the moment, I'll correct if someone can confirm this).

So you want one big vector now, so I'll just collapse all that.

```
do.call(c, lapply(1:NTR, foo_outer))
```

I can then just assign this value to `F` directly:

```
F <- do.call(c, lapply(1:NTR, foo_outer))
```

Obviously, I can't ensure this is exactly what you wanted without knowing what `F`, `YTR`, `Y` and all your inputs are. But I hope it gets you started on the right path!

Edit: I think I created the wrong order for your final vector: with the above it will put all the "j" values for `i= 1` then all the "j" values for `i = 2`... But looking back at your `F`, it looks like the order you want is for `j=1` all the "i" values... To do this, You just have to rearrange the output of your second `lapply`. This hould work.

I want to create a function that will get all `j` elements from the list:

```
LL <- lapply(1:NTR, foo_outer)
get_j_values <- function(j) {
    sapply(LL, function(x) x[[j]])
}
```

For any `j` value, `get_j_value` returns in a vector all the `j`th element of `LL`. By applying this function to all possible `j` values, it returns a list with first element: all "i" values for `j=1` then for the second element all "i" values for `j=2`...

```
LL2 <- lapply(1:NOUT, get_j_values)
```

I can then collapse this list in one big vector and assign it.

```
F <- do.call(c, LL2)
```

Edit 2: Although it is possible to work with `apply` functions to recreate your for loop, this might be one of these times where a for loop is actually better: there is no accumulation of result so the `apply` method shouldn't be faster and the for loop would be clearer I believe. This is usually the case when you are looping over indices that are used over several different objects so that you can't use an `apply` on any specific object directly but need to apply a function to a vector of indices... Just my two cents...

Comment: This is wonderful, more than any tutorial has shown me. I still need to understand how a function inside a function definition works, but I can read up.

F and Y are vectors, YTR is a matrix (all numeric) so Y[j]-YTR[i,j] is a number. It just has to be put in the right place in the vector F. FN is a function of matrices W, V, U and vector X. (XTR is a data frame because I read it from a file with read.csv.)

I don't understand the last part - LL and LL2. We are not creating any lists at all. Only YZ is a list because I want to return two matrices from FN. Thanks again for the explanation.

Comment: Use `foo_inner <- function(i) function(j) paste("i=", i, "j=", j)` and run it, then compare `F` as created by the first method and `F` as created by the second, this should make the difference between `LL` and `LL2` clearer. I use a list here simply to make sure I put the correct values in the correct place.

Comment: I'm glad you found it useful.

Comment: @user6439024, you can accept Choubi's answer by clicking on the grey shaded tick mark next to his answer and you can give his answer a "+1" by also clicking on the upward pointing arrow above the tick mark